# VMware Host Copy File from catalog to VM/ISO mounting not working

Tags: vmware-server, windows, vmware-vcloud-director

I have uploaded an ISO to our vcloud administrator organization catalog.

For some reason the system refuses to mount it as a CD/DVD drive.  It recognizes that it's an ISO, but when I select it as the file in the catalog to mount on the system nothing happens.  No error, it just tells me it's busy for a few seconds and then nothing happens, no disk is mounted.

Can I copy a file from the catalog directly to a hard drive on a guest OS?  Alternatively, can I browse the host catalog from a guest OS?

Failing all that, is there any reason I can't mount Microsoft ISOs on a guest VM?

Comment: Just an idea, did you try re-uploading the ISO? Perhaps corrupted file?

Comment: Yeah, we tried that a number of times. In the end it turned out that you have to name the file *.iso.  You can't upload it and tell the system that it's an iso, you have to force the issue.